# How to make the transparency of my objects back to normal?

Tags: materials, interface, transparency

I was making a well, and I think I clicked a button and it turned all transparent

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIDJe.png]

How can i get it back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have enabled the viewport [X-Ray](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/introduction.html#display-shading) shading option.

[image]

You probably enabled it with the shortcut <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.